# Esoterical language, ComeFrom command

Tags: conditional-statements, goto, esoteric-languages

One of the esoteric languages introduce `ComeFrom` command, which is opposite of `Goto`:

```
10 ComeFrom 30
20
30 ...
```

Equals to:

```
10 ...
20 ...
30 Goto 10
```

My question is: how to implement a conditional jump with `ComeFrom`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said it would be just a "reversed goto". So do it like you would do it normally but instead writing got to the origin of the jumo, write ComeFrom to the destination

```
10 ComeFrom 80
20 ... Do something when Codition is true
30 ...
...
...
70 If condition Do
80 ...
90 ComeFrom 30
```

*(I'm not quite sure if i understood your problem correct)*

Out of interest: Which language are you referring to ?

Comment: From what I remember, it seems to be INTERCAL.